# insert in to table gives back ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I need to insert a row in my table in oracle from C# (Windows Forms)

```
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO RECIPES(id,name,time_cooking,time_prep,price,directions,user_name,submit_timestamp) VALUES (:id, :name, :time_cook, :time_prep, :price, :directions, :user_name, :sub_time)",conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":id",x);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":name",textBox10.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":time_cook", textBox9.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":time_prep",textBox8.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":price", textBox6.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":directions",richTextBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":user_name",this.username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":sub_time",DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

conn.Close();
```

I get the error below.

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

I checked in oracle :

```
select * 
from nls_session_parameters;
```

and returned NLS_DATE_FORMAT mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Why are you converting the date to a string?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the date as a string; you should pass it as a date instead... just remove the `ToString` call:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":sub_time", DateTime.Now);
```

If you pass a string, it will be parsed using the format specified by the `nls_date_format` parameter in the database. If the format you pass is not the one the database expects, the parsing will fail. By passing the date itself, you don't need to worry about the format.

Comment: On the way in, wouldn't it be parsed according to the settings *on the client* which may not match up with the server. I recently had this error, because my user was typing "05/27/2013" and Oracle wanted "27-MAY-2013" for some reason. Turns out, it wasn't the server throwing the error, it was her machine.

Comment: @Jasmine, the settings on the client only matter if you're converting the date to a string on the client... If you're passing the date directly as a date, there's no reason to format it in any way, so the format settings on the client or the server have no effect.